# Collection view cell with expandable view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell, uicollectionviewcell

I have horizontal collection view inside regular ViewController. Each cell should be expandable to 3/5 of the full screen size after tapping on in and should be presented as pop-up (blurred background, disabled scrolling, until the cell will be collapsed back). For all of my project I am using Storyboards and Swift. See the mockups below:

[image: This should be the expanded state]
[image: This is what I already have, collapsed state]

**Is there any way how to do same cell in storyboard with collapsed and expanded view?**

**If there is no way to do it with storyboards, how should I proceed with code?**

Thank you!

Comment: When you want to expand / collapse the cell update the internal constraints with an animation.

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. But what is the best way of creating a layout of the cell? I need to have in expanded state at least 6 new buttons, multiple labels, etc. On collapsed cell, just 2 labels. What approach should I take ? Create expanded cell with stackviews and hide it on collapse or is there any better and easier way?

Comment: Store two constraints, the first (for the collapsed state) constraint the bottom of the cell to the bottom of the second label, the second (for the expanded state) constraint the bottom of the last view to the bottom of the cell. Then when collapse / expand the cell you activate the related constraint and deactivate the other. You could also leave all the view placed and change only two constraints dynamically.

Comment: Sorry but I don’t get it. I should create a expanded cell and layout for the expanded cell - with constraints. On collapsing I will activate the other constraints for collapsed cell and hide all the stuff which I want to hide?

Comment: Set up the layout of the cell (config your `UICollectionView` to use dynamic items height) by defining constraints that are valid when collapsed and also when expanded, and never change them. Then creates some variables for contain the constraints defining the anchors that change when the view is collapsed / expanded, depending on the state activate / deactivate them (for example defines a constraint with a lower cell bottom anchor and another with a higher cell bottom anchor). There is not need to hide your views, because if the cell is collapsed they are not included anyway.

Comment: I will try and get back to you! Thank you